# Laravel filter by query string

Tags: php, laravel

I pass a query in url`?color=green&&size=xxl;`

In my controller I get the query with

```
$request->query();
```

It returns

```
  {"color":"green","size":"xxl"}
```

How do I search the table variations where the *'option'* column should have **'color'** and **'size'** and the corresponding *'values'* column should have 'green and 'xxl'

**edit**
This is the `Variation` model

```
class Variation extends Model
{
     public function sku()
     {
        return $this->belongsTo(Sku::class);
     }

     public function opt()
     {
        return $this->belongsTo(Option::class, 'option_id');
     }

     public function product()
     {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
     }
}
```

the Controller Method:

```
 public function productQ(Request $request,$slug,$sku)
    {    

        $query = $request->query();
        $condition = [];

        Variation::where($query)->get();

    }
```

**Update:**
Alihossein shahabi's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51125976/7599905) works with a little modification

```
 $my_query=Variation::query();
  foreach ($request->query() as $key=>$value)
  {
      $my_query->where('option',$key)->where('value',$value);
  }

   return   $result= $my_query->get();
```

Comment: Can u upload the `Model` & controller's `method`?

Comment: Please see my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this code :

```
$my_query=Variation::query();
foreach ($request->query() as $key=>$value)
{
    $my_query->where($key,$value);
}

$result= $my_query->get();
```

or you can see your `SQL` by using `dd($my_query->toSql());` insted of `$my_query->get();`

Comment: returns select * from `variations` where `color` = ?" . But I want my query to be select * from `variations` where `option` = `color` AND value = `green`

Comment: no. this is OK.. please test.`toSql()` method does not show value in your query Because of security issues

Comment: ‍‍use must use `$result= $my_query->get();` line for get result

Answer (score 1):

Please Try

```
public function productQ(Request $request,$slug,$sku)
{    
    $query = new Variation();

    $searchable = $query->getFillable();
    $queryParams = $request->all();

    foreach ($queryParams as $field => $value) {
        if (in_array($field, $searchable) {
            $query = $query->where($field, $value);
        }
    }

    $variations = $query->get();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But what if want to search more than just color and size? that's why I pass them through the url

Comment: Sorry, this returns all the rows

Comment: Add `$fillable` props  to your model

Comment: Another way `$searchable = ['color',  'size', 'price' ,....]` i.e all searchble fields name.

Comment: I want my query to be like ->where('option' , $key) -> where('value', $value) from the array

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Products::where(function($query) {
    $query->where('option', '=', 'color')->where('values', '=', 'green')
})
->where(function($query) {
    $query->where('option', '=', 'size')->where('values', '=', 'xxl')
});
```

Comment: but the parameters are dynamic not just 'color' and 'size'